# how to estimate profit from pools?

Tags: mining-pools, hashrate, mining-profitability

For what I've seen so far this topic hasn't been adressed before.

In my case I have a crap computer with an **intel i3** with a hash rata around 27h/s. Obviously there is no way to make profit with such a low hash rate, so I thought maybe I should join a pool.

The calculators however regarding pools are a bit confusing to me.

For example, I know that in a pool each miner gets a share according to what he gives. So if a pool has *487Mh/s* does this mean I will get a decent share?

How can I estimate the profit in my case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not consider the pool hash rate in your profits calculation.
Pool hash rate influence the variance in block finding frequency but not your profit. A lower pool find less blocks but you get a bigger reward of each.

For your calculation take the ((your hashrate) / (the network hashrate)) * (720 blocks per day) * (block reward) = XMR/day

Comment: Thank you for answer. I've got 0.000083678 based on the above calculations. That means that every 120 seconds I'll be rewarded 0.000083678 correct?

Comment: Sorry, i messed up with the formula. I should be ((your hashrate) / (the network hashrate)) * (720 blocks per day) * (block reward) to have the amount in XMR per day. So around 0,000171 for you.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using minergate, they have their own easy to use calculator.
just use the cryptonote tab.

after you get teh estimated weekly gains, my RPi 3B goes at around 16 mBTC equiv., multiply the amount by the value of bitcoin.

If you know the wattage of the device and the price per kW/h in your area, you can calculate the rest.

Fomula:

```
(amt in BTC per week * value of BTC) - ((24 * 7 * device wattage) / 1000) * cost per kW/h = weekly profit

My Case:
(0.0016 * 7300) - ((24 * 7 * 12.75) / 1000) * 0.11 = $11.44
```

My Pi will only bring in about $45 a month, but it is profitable!

You need to input your local power cost and computer wattage, but you can expect to earn about 18.3 mBTC per week.